# Regex for matching specific numbers separated by comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex which matches any combination of the number 1,7 and 99, separated by commas. E.g. these should be matched:

```
1
1,7
1,99
99,1,7
```

While these should not match:

```
1,
8
8,99
,7
1,7,99,
```

The following works fine, but can probably be shortened and made more efficient?

```
/^(1|7|99)(,?(1|7|99)(,?(1|7|99))?)?$/
```

Comment: Does it only have to check 1, 7 and 99?

Comment: your example regex matches 17, say

Comment: @Goudgeld1 Yes, that's right.

Comment: As it stands you would also match dups; 1,7,7 is this correct?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala You're right, that was not the intention.

Comment: @AlexK. You're right. That's not the intention either. I obviously have a few things to learn about regexes.

Comment: Are you matching a single token or extracting from some text?

Comment: `'99,1,7'.split(',').every(function(x) { return [1,7,99].indexOf(+x) != -1 });`

Comment: @AlexK. It's a single token.

Comment: @adeneo Thanks, but I would like it to be a regex query. I tagged it with javascript because that's where I'll be using it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookahead based regex:

```
/^(1|7|99)(?!.*?,\1)(?:,(?:1|7|99))*$/gm
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mY8pV7/4)

Comment: My God! You made that in 2 minutes!?!? Is it possible to restrict it a little further, so that it matches the numbers only one time each? (1,7,99)

Comment: @anubhava Can I just ask why you've put (1|77|99) and not (1|7|99)?

Comment: I like it! However, like my original query this one also matches e.g. 99,11111,777 (which it should not)

Answer (score 1):

```
/^(1|7|99)(,(1|7|99))*$/
```

tested using your test cases on [rubular](http://rubular.com/)

Comment: Your regex matches 77,99 too. I modified it little bit `^(1|7|99)(,(1|7|99){1})*$`

Answer (score 0):

Modifying @RidesTheShortBus's answer little bit works perfectly for all test cases

```
^(1|7|99)(,(1|7|99){1})*$
```

Tests [here](https://regex101.com/r/zM0uC2/1)